# Read created files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working with where I use watchdogs to be able read whenever I have created a file by the name -> *kill_*.flag and it contains:

```
*kill_*.flag contains:

hello;https://www.google.se/;123
```

and my script is then going to read the created file, split the ";" between each other and give each a key where I later on print it out which I for now has the text "Deleting" where I will continue my script after I have completed this part.

```py
# !/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import os.path
import time

import watchdog.events
import watchdog.observers


class AutomaticCreate(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        self.delete_flag = "*kill_*.flag"
        watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=[os.path.split(self.delete_flag)[1]],
                                                             case_sensitive=False)

    def on_created(self, event):
        while True:
            try:
                with open(event.src_path) as f:
                    content = f.read().split(";")
                    payload = {
                        "name": content[0].strip(),
                        "link": content[1].strip(),
                        "id": content[2].strip()
                    }
                break
            except OSError:
                print(f"Waiting for file to transfer ->  {event.src_path}")
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

        while True:
            try:
                os.remove(event.src_path)
                break
            except Exception as err:
                print(f"Trying to remove file -> {err}")
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

        print(f'Deleting: {payload["name"]} - {payload["link"]} - {payload["id"]}')

    def main(self):
        observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
        observer.schedule(AutomaticCreate(), path=os.path.split(self.delete_flag)[0], recursive=True)
        observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AutomaticCreate().main()
```

I wonder if there is a smarter or maybe even cleaner way to improve this code both performance and whatever it can be?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Python 3 :) @Reinderien

Comment: Ok. Please file a new question with your updated code. In the meantime I'll need to roll back your edit to this one.

Comment: I have now created a new question in here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257341/read-created-json-files-inside-a-given-folder :) @Reinderien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I genuinely hope you don't take offence by this, but this implementation is so insane that it's frankly impressive.

Since you have `delete_flag = "*kill_*.flag"`, calling `os.path.split` on it is pointless. Perhaps you're substituting that with something else that has a path, but if you are, why isn't it parametrized?

Do a tuple-unpack here:

```
                    content = f.read().split(";")
                    payload = {
                        "name": content[0].strip(),
                        "link": content[1].strip(),
                        "id": content[2].strip()
                    }
```

should just be

```
name, link, id = (part.strip() for part in f.read().split(';'))
```

Putting these in a `payload` dict is actively harmful. You only ever use these as variables later. About the most generous I can be here is to guess that there's actually more code in your application that you haven't shown which relies on the payload for some other network or serialized file operation, but if that's the case the whole question is invalid.

`AutomaticCreate` implements `PatternMatchingEventHandler` - so then why are you reinstantiating it here?

```
        observer.schedule(AutomaticCreate()
```

You already instantiated it here:

```
AutomaticCreate().main()
```

Keep the second instantiation, and replace the first instantiation with a reference to `self`.

The following is a strange and non-standard way of calling a base constructor:

```
    watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=[os.path.split(self.delete_flag)[1]],  # ...
```

Just use `super()`.

Rework your class to be a context manager, where `__enter__` calls `self.observer.start()`, and `__exit__` calls `self.observer.stop()`. Then, use your class instance in a `with` at the top level and delete your `main()` method.

Comment: `name, link, id = (part.strip() for part in f.read().split(';'))` I think I more elegant way would be `name, link, id = map(str.strip, f.read().split(';'))`

Comment: elegant but harder to read ;)

Comment: I have now created a new (Well updated the thread) with the new code with your guidens! Could you please look at it again and tell me if there is anything im missing? :)